# How to correctly use Spark in ScalaTest tests?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I have multiple ScalaTest classes which use `BeforeAndAfterAll` to construct a `SparkContext` and stop it afterwards like so:

```
class MyTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  private var sc: SparkContext = null

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    sc = ... // Create SparkContext
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    sc.stop()
  }

  // my tests follow
}
```

These tests run fine when started from IntelliJ IDEA, but when running `sbt test`, I get `WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243).`, and after that, a bunch of other exceptions which are, I suppose, related to this issue.

How to correctly use Spark? Do I have to create one global `SparkContext` for the whole test suite, and if yes, how do I do this?

Comment: I found this [(PDF) Testing Spark Best Practices](https://spark-summit.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Testing-Spark-Best-Practices-Anupama-Shetty-Neil-Marshall.pdf)

Comment: Do you still have the PDF file please? Could you share it somewhere? The link doesn't work anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I lost the sight of the wood for the trees, I forgot the following line in my `build.sbt`:

```
parallelExecution in test := false
```

With this line, the test runs.