# What is the right way to use ScalaTest's BeforeAndAfterAll trait with sbt and IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

I'm attempting to set up a testing framework for Spark jobs. I'd like to use [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base)'s SharedSparkContext trait which relies on ScalaTest's BeforeAndAfterAll trait to manage setup and tear-down. Something about my current environment is causing the beforeAll and afterAll methods to be called around each test case.

(Even if I wanted to permit this redundant behavior, I couldn't: I don't know how to tear down my HiveContext object properly, so the second call to beforeAll throws an exception that bottoms out at "ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /Users/applemacbookpro/git/my-project/metastore_db.")

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with an SBT-managed build.

- MacOS 10.11.4
- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3
- not sure about SBT version, should be recent
- ScalaTest 2.2.6

Per the README of spark-testing-base and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237856/how-to-correctly-use-spark-in-scalatest-tests), I've put

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

in build.sbt.

Here's my example:

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FlatSpec}

class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    println("in beforeAll")
    super.beforeAll()
  }

  override def afterAll() {
    println("in afterAll")
    super.afterAll()
  }

  behavior of "example"

  it should "succeed" in {
    println("test 1")
  }

  it should "succeed again" in {
    println("test2")
  }
}
```

I trigger it by right-clicking in the editor window and running from the context menu; the output is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java...
Testing started at 2:50 PM ...
in beforeAll
test 1
in afterAll
in beforeAll
test2
in afterAll

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Was unable to reproduce with Windows-7 / IntelliJ-2016.2 / SBT-0.13.12 / ScalaTest-2.2.6 for both Scala-2.10 and Scala-2.11.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's and Intellij/Scalatest bug.

I can reproduce your case, when right-clicking in the "Editor" window.

But if you right click on your class in the "Project" window and then run from the context menu, it works as expected :

```
in beforeAll
test 1
test2
in afterAll
```

When right-clicking in the editor window, Intellij seems to instantiate 2 runners, one for each test method. 
You can see in the "Run/Debug" window that `ExampleSpec` class appears several times instead of once.

Comment: Oh wow, I gave up on that and wrote a kludge to get around the problem months ago. (The kludge is to do the setup in an object; first-class singletons for the win, I guess.)